# Caching all entities in Cache Layer and Synchronizing with Database

Tags: caching, model-view-controller

Is it possible, reliable and secure to cache all entities in distrubuted cache and notifies dao layer on update? My possible idea is;

- Use JPA 2.1 and Hibernate implementation.
- On creation persist it db
- After persisting it, cache it to distrubuted cache.
- Canalise all read actions to cache
- on update notify dao layer to update entity .

Answer (score 0):

yes you can design a system that will

- On addition: persists data to db and adds to cache
- On read: reads data from cache, and considers a cache miss as not
  present in database as well.
- On update: updates data in db and then updates in cache (or vice
  versa)
- On delete: deletes data from cache and then deletes from database

This approach will work fine if you have a single application using that database and if data is not that critical. However if data integrity is of more importance, you may face following problems in this approach:

- You may face a cache miss when data is present in database(persisted
  but not yet cached)
- You may get stale data from cache (updated in db but not yet updated 
  in cache)
- Also if data is removed from database by some other application, it
  will still ramained cached in distributed cache(invalid data on
  reads)

A better mothod my be if you use a rich featured distributed caching solution like [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/) / [Tayzgrid](http://www.alachisoft.com/tayzgrid/) which provides [Read Trough / Write behind features](http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/articles/readthru-writethru-writebehind.html). This way your application will only need to use cache for all reads, writes or updates and cache will keep database updated using configured providers.

Another approach may be to use distributed cache as hibernate's second level cache and you will not need to add a caching layer by your self. See [this article](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/02/how-hibernate-second-level-cache-works/) for details about hibernate's second level cache.

Distributed caching solutions like Tayzgrid provide [caching provider for hibernate](http://www.alachisoft.com/tayzgrid/hibernate-second-level-cache.html) that can be easily configured. You can find hibernate providers for other solutions as well.